# Magento 2 - Having trouble collecting totals for a custom gift card module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, quote, totals

I'm in the process of adding support for a 3rd party gift card system. These cards will not exist in any way within the context of Magento, and an external web based API will validate/confirm balance/etc.

With that in mind, I simply need a way to alter the final cost of the order by adding one or more gift cards.

I feel like I'm close, but I'm getting very confused by how totals collection works in regards to `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` and `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total`, specifically their `->getBaseGrandTotal()`/`->setBaseGrandTotal()`/`->getGrandTotal()`/`->setGrandTotal()` methods.

`$total->get[Base]GrandTotal()` always seem to come back with a `null` or `0` value, even after calling `$total->set[Base]GrandTotal(1234)`;

Here is my current `collect()` method, which seems to be not affecting the order total cost at all.

```
public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

    $baseGrandTotal = $total->getGrandTotal(); //this is always zero!
    $totalGiftCardBalance = $this->_CardSessionHelper->GetTotalAvailableBalanceOfCurrentGiftCards();

    $giftCardContribution = min($baseGrandTotal, $totalGiftCardBalance);
    //this takes the total viable gift card amount and spreads it over multiple gift cards
    //depending on how much balance each one has 
    $this->_CardSessionHelper->AllocateToGiftCards($giftCardContribution);

    //$contribution is a negative value determined by the previous allocation
    $contribution = $this->_CardSessionHelper->GetSumOfCurrentGiftCardsContribution();
    $total->setGrandTotal($contribution);
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($this->_PriceCurrency->convert($contribution));

    return $this;
}
```

I've had other variations of this method which `$quote->set[Base]GrandTotal`, and seemed to work for the most part, but trying to work out additional gift card contributions after the fact would result in negative quote total values, or other values that made little sense.

In addition to this, the collection seems to happen multiple times - I presume this is because of both billing and shipping addresses.

Is there a way to get it to work for **a billing address only**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Collect Totals:**

We should base on shipping address.

`\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::collectTotals` (can be called at the first) loops through each quote address (quote address total):

```
 $total = $this->totalsCollector->collect($this);
```

The `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector::collect()` and `collectAddressTotals()` will be called for the next step

`\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector::collectAddressTotals()`

```
 foreach ($this->collectorList->getCollectors($quote->getStoreId()) as $collector) {
            /** @var CollectorInterface $collector */
            $collector->collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
 }
```

In the foreach loop, we will get the collect total of each total Model, for example: `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal::collect()`, `Magento\Weee\Model\Total\Quote\Weee::collect()`, `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount::collect()`. Our custom total will be called in this loop also.

Each total Model based on the shipping address.

So, we need to check: if having shipping address items, we will process the custom totals

For example, in the collect method, we need to check: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Quote/Discount.php`

```
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

    $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
```

Or (your case can be used)

```
if ($shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress()->getAddressType() != Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return $this;
}
```

---

**Grand Totals:**

As far as I know, **the grand total is the "final" total after tax, discount,...**.

- `setBaseGrandTotal`: the grand total bases on base currency.
- `setGrandTotal` : bases on the current currency.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that helped clarify a couple things for me.

Am still somewhat confused about how to actually alter the order's total as a part of this process however. 

It appears that I should be doing `$total->set[Base]Subtotal(...)` and `$total->set[Base]SubtotalWithDiscount(...)`, but neither of those seem to have any result.

I can see where those values are used in `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector::collect()`'s `foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) ` loop, but that function's `$total` is returned without being applied to the `$quote` object.

Comment: @Danzapps did you try to hard code the grand total value? for example: `$total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + 400);`.

Comment: You can take a look my module here: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee/blob/master/Boolfly/PaymentFee/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Fee.php#L76

Comment: I have tried `$total->setGrandTotal(...)`, but that doesn't seem quite right as `$total->getGrandTotal()` always returns `null`. Even `$total->getShippingDescription()` returns `null`... Regardless, setting the sub/grand total values on my `$total` seems to have no impact.

Makes me wonder if I have something else misconfigured.

Comment: Actually, using `$total->set[Base]TotalAmount('gift_cards', $contribution)` seems to be working now. The Order's total is being adjusted as I'd hope!  Next I need to determine what the shipping amount actually is, as the gift cards need to work out their contribution based on that as well (currently the sub total is only for the items in the cart)

Comment: Yeah! Additionally, you can see the total data in table `quote`, `sales_order`.

Comment: Got it!! Getting access to `$total->getShippingAmount()` was as simple as making sure the `sort_order` attribute in `sales.xml` was just before the grand total's `sort_order`, eg, `sort_order="500"` .

Thanks very much for your assistance :)